# Change sound output device to different version of the same device

Tags: audio, windows-11, bluetooth

I have some wirless bluetooth headphones.

How can I change between the different output version of this same device that shows up twice in my Playback devices.

[image]

I want to connect to the other version of these Bose headphones. I've tried disabling the current one and re-connecting, I've tried right clicking on the one I want to be connected to and pressing "Connect". Nothing works.

I want to connect to the headphones version, not the headset one.

Comment: I just took a look through the blurb on Bose's website - it says that the headphones can be paired to two devices at the same time - is the Headphones "component" paired to a different device - hence preventing you from pairing that with windows?

Comment: I tried that. I turned off my phone's bluetooth and restarted the headset and it still didn't work.

Comment: Not sure if it works on Win 11 (wil check later) but on WIn 10: Open Control Panel, Open Devices and Printers, Select your device, right click on it and open its properties. Switch to Services tab, unckech "HandsFree". Itg removes HandsFree profile drivers from your PC and leaves only Headset.